# Whats the 3rd argument in VertexAttribute() used for in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hay, I'm going through the basic tutorial on libgdx's wiki, and I'm confused by the line

```
new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"));
```

What is the string "a_position" used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Mesh class works with OpenGL ES 1.x and 2.0. In OpenGL ES 1.x you use a fixed function pipeline (no shaders). Here the attribute does not have any use. In OpenGL ES 2.0 you write so called vertex and fragment shaders. If you send a Mesh (or rather its vertices) to your vertex/fragment shader pair, your shaders have to have a way to identify specific vertex attributes, say the vertex position, texture coordinates, colors and so on.

Shaders are written in a language called GLSL. A vertex shader could look like this:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 u_projView;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    v_color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    v_texCoords = a_TexCoord;
    gl_Position = u_projView * a_Position;
}
```

As you can see there are so called attributes which are exactly the same as VertexAttributes in libgdx. The 3rd parameter is thus the name of a VertexAttribute as used in a shader (and hence ShaderProgram in libgdx, if you use that for convenience instead of going with straight GLES 2.0 functions).

hth,
Mario

Comment: So, the 3rd argument, can be ANY word. Which we an pass onto the ShaderProgram? I could call it "funbags" and that would work?

Answer (score -1):

See the doc for [VertexAttribute](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/VertexAttribute.html#VertexAttribute%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It says "the alias for the attribute used in a ShaderProgram", meaning?