# What is integer parameter to the VertexAttribute constructor in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

In libgdx [Mesh, Color, Texture tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshcolorTexture) a Mesh representing a simple triangle, with color and texture information for each vertex is created by:

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, 
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoords"));
```

In the `VertexAttribute` constructors what is the integer argument?  The doc says its the "number of components" needed to encode the information.

I read that as the number of entries in the 'vertex' array (an array of floats) that each entry uses.  So, for the first `VertexAttribute` that is 3, which makes sense (one each for x, for y, and for z).  However, the ColorPacked attribute has 4 but but since the color data gets encoded into a single float, shouldn't this be 1?   Finally the texture coordinates are added (that gets 2, which matches the two float u,v coordinates needed for each vertex).

The [javadoc for the VertexAttribute constructor](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/VertexAttribute.html#VertexAttribute%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) says this parameter is:

```
numComponents - the number of components of this attribute, must be between 1 and 4.
```

Note an older question,
[Whats the 3rd argument in VertexAttribute() used for in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814927/whats-the-3rd-argument-in-vertexattribute-used-for-in-libgdx), covers the 3rd argument to this constructor, so we just need one more SO question to cover the first.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numComponents integer parameter to the VertextAttribute constructor is the "size" argument to gl*Pointer

- Usage.Position -> glVertexPointer
- Usage.Color -> glColorPointer
- Usage.ColorPacked -> glColorPointer
- Usage.TextureCoordinates -> glTexCoordPointer
- Usage.Normal -> glNormalPointer

Using the ColorPacked attribute changes the "type" argument of the call to glColorPointer from  GL10.GL_FLOAT to GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. The color needs 4 bytes so you need to set the "numComponents" argument to 4.

Source: [VertexArray.bind()](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/VertexArray.java) and [glColorPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml)

Answer (score 0):

It's the number of components in your shader, not the cpu-sided calculations. When you pass a position-vector to the shader, 4 says, that your vector is encoded into a vec4 in your shader.

Same is with colors: You may pass a packed single float value to shader, but you'll be working with a vec4 color vector in your shader.